# VUE Toggle child component element visibility

Tags: vue.js, components, vuetify.js, toggle

I am trying to toggle the visibility of an span element using v-if within a child component. I am basically trying to use the @click toggle (Vuetify) with $refs. Not very savvy with code, but my research has not yielded a solution.

PARENT

```vue
<v-switch 
  label="hide manufacturer" 
  @click="$refs.childComponent.hideManf()"
/>

<child-component ref="childComponent" />

components: {
  childComponent
}
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
<span v-if="spanManf">Name to Hide</span>

data() {
    return {
        spanManf: true
    };
},
methods: {
        hideManf () {
        this.spanManf = !this.spanManf;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use props in your child component, and pass the data from the parent something like this.

```vue
<span v-if="visible">Name to Hide</span>

props: {
   visible: { type: Boolean, required: true }
}
```

And then in your parent

```vue
<child-compoent :visible="spanManf" />

<v-switch label="hide manufacturer" @click="spanManf = !spanManf" />

data() {
   return {
      spanManf: true,
   }
}
```

Comment: I changed v-if="spanManf" from your code to v-if="visible" and your solution then worked. Thank you!